# Pegar a posição em um loop for em java?

Tags: java, android, loop, for

Meu código java:

```java
for (Construtor usuario: users){

Construtor USER = new Construtor(user.getNomeUsuario);

arrayList.add(USER);

}
```

** Como eu pego a posição do loop nessa configuração acima? Veja que da maneira antiga é mais fácil pois:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){

Toast......"Posição" + i.......Show();

}
```

** É mais fácil da maneira antiga, mas eu quero saber como faz da outra maneira.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96471/discussion-on-question-by-cavalo-branco-alas-por-que-meu-expandable-listview-nao) - Quanto ao post, reduza o código a um [mcve] do problema, para evitar mais desencontros de informação e viabilizar a reabertura.

Comment: Não altere sua pergunta, faça ela de forma adequada na primeira vez. Quando você altera a pergunta  depois que tem uma resposta você invalida esta resposta e não é justo co ma pessoa que respondeu. Por isso é importante fazer a pergunta de forma adequada logo de cara, e é por isso que perguntas que não estão boas precisam ser fechada o mais rápido possível, para evitar que respostas ruins sejam dadas porque a pergunta está em forma ruim.

Answer (score 1):

Olá existe sim uma forma de pegar posição e o valor.

Veja um exemplo:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int index = 0;
        int[] abc = {2,5};
        for (int ho : abc) {
            System.out.println(ho+" is from index: "+index);
            index += 1;
        }
        index = undefined;
    }
}
```

Console:

```
2 is from index: 0
5 is from index: 1
```

E no segundo método dar pegar valor e a posição.

Veja um exemplo:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] abc = {2,5};
        for (int i = 0;i<abc.length;i++) {
            int value = abc[i];
            System.out.println(value+" is from index: "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Console:

```
2 is from index: 0
5 is from index: 1
```

- OBS: Essa resposta foi da primeira pergunta antes de editar.

Comment: kkkkkk desculpe ter feito você ter o trabalho de responder.... agradeço muito muito muito pela sua explicação

Comment: Veja na edição.... na minha MainActivity que no qual tinha esses loops "for"..... eu acha que o erro estava ali.... mas vi que não...

Comment: Ok beleza. Qual linha do código que ter erros?

Comment: Pois é eu não sei..... A intensão é expandir o listView mostrando os childs, mas quando eu clico no grupo nada acontece..... Eu procurei por erros, mas nada eu encontro.....

Comment: Qual Code editor tu usar?

Comment: Não entendi bem essa última pergunta, mas se você está falando de linguagem de programação é java e se for plataforma é Android Studio.....

Comment: Se você quiser eu posso te mandar o .Apk para você dá uma olhada junto com o código fonte....

Comment: Android Studio tem console?

Comment: Não precisa manda. Você ja mandou o código na resposta .

Comment: Tudo em então..... mas se quiser ver o ponto apk eu te mando

Answer (score 0):

No Java, não existe uma construção nativa para obter o index do Iterable. Algumas linguagens permitem isso. Por exemplo, em PHP:

```php
foreach ($items as $key => $value) { ... }
```

No entanto, para fazer o mesmo em Java, você terá que controlar o `index` por conta própria. Exemplo:

```java
int index = 0;

for(Construtor usuario: users) {
    System.out.println("Index atual: " + (index++));
}
```

Outra alternativa, como colocada por você, é usar a forma padrão do `for` (sem a iteração do Iterable):

```java
for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Index atual: " + i);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo.....Você realmente entendeu a pergunta e deu uma ótima resposta.